# Can an adverb modify an article?

Tags: articles, adverbs

In English, can an adverb modify an article?
If so, I'd like to see an example sentence.

I have come across some claims that an adverb can modify everything but a noun/pronoun. This means that it can modify an article, but I have not seen this in any of the grammar books or dictionaries I have used. The claim did not mention the word *article* let alone give an example.

Comment: This is merely an example, but how do you parse "merely an example"?

Comment: Nice example, Gary. *a* and *mere*, each modifies *example* in "a mere example", so *merely*, assuming it is an adverb, must modify "an example", specifically modifying *an* because *example* is a noun. If that sounds strange, then how about the verb to be *is*? Why would not *merely* modify *is*? Both cases are odd. However, one must be correct. If so, why not the other?

Comment: 1. This is *merely* an example  2. This *merely is* an example. By contrasting the two sentences, it looks like *merely* in 1 modifies *an* while *merely* modifies *is* in 2. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.  Those are the relationships that I find natural as a native speaker.

Comment: If *OP wants **the** answer, not **just an** answer*, will this serve as an example of ***just*** adverbially modifying the article ***an**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's **just** *the thing* I was looking for, I guess. However, what's your take on "This **merely is** an example" vs "This is **merely an** example"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe they are the same and the auditory stress is equivalent to an articulated sentence adverb such as *indeed/in fact* e.g. "In fact, this is merely an example".

Comment: @learner: Even allowing for ridiculously contrived contexts, it's not easy to come up with contexts where the specific verb [TO BE] can be adverbially "weakened" with something like ***just, only, merely***. I'd say it's semantically / pragmatically *impossible* to parse your *merely is an example* like that, so it's just an "unusual, non-idiomatic" variation on the standard word sequence. But you could certainly do what you're getting at if you include negation: *You not only **are** the best worker on my team. I'll see to it that everyone else **knows** you're the best.*

Comment: I have found out that *not only* is part of a parallel construction, namely the correlative conjunction (*not only ... but also*). When diagramed, it is no different from (*both ... and*) or (*n/either ... n/or*). As for **knows**, I must be missing something because I failed to see how it related to the examples except the sentence has two that-clauses--Aha, as I'm writing I'm guessing you mean **know** is a linking verb, a copulative! But then again, I am not sure what you are trying to get at with the know-example. Sorry if I failed you.

Comment: "I have come across some claims"  this needs to be substantiated.  Please cite details or provide a link to these claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting problem. The thing to remember, though, is that articles aren't independent words. They are used only as determiners of nouns, and fulfil no grammatical role otherwise. There are various examples in the the comments, such as

> This is merely an example

And the question is, what does *merely* modify. Actually, what it appears to modify is *a noun phrase*, "an example", but that would be strange - if it can't modify a noun, surely it can't modify a noun phrase?

What you're actually seeing here is an area that linguists get into arguments about. Sometimes you see an adverb that doesn't appear to be modifying an identifiable verb or adjective. Linguists then tie themselves in knots trying to come up with an explanation that doesn't contradict the nice, simple basic explanations people get taught in school.

Sometimes, it's easy. Sometimes, it's an adverb modifying an entire clause:

> Suddenly, a voice cried out.

The adverb is prepended to the clause and modifies the whole thing, with a subtly different meaning to "a voice suddenly cried out". Such whole-clause adverbs can also be appended, placed after the clause. They don't generally apply to the whole clause when placed in the middle of it, though.

But it's not modifying *is*. It's unusual, but you can say:

> This merely is an example.

However, then you're not saying that all it is is an example, as you are with the *merely* after *is*. You're insisting that it is an example, a difference that is clearer if you use the nearly synonymous (in this context) *simply*:

> This is simply an example
>   This simply is an example

The first would be used to reassure people that *this* is just being used as an example, not as something that they should worry about in itself. The second would be used if someone were arguing about whether it was an example, and you were insisting - using certain sorts of argument - that it was.

So, if *merely* or *simply* appears after *is*, what is it modifying? Some linguists will say it's modifying a noun phrase, with the explanation that **some** adverbs can modify **some** noun phrases in **some** situations. Some linguists will say it is modifying the determiner, with arguments against it modifying the noun phrase being that it can't modify an arbitrary noun phrase. However, it's not always as simple as that. The meaning of the adverb depends on what the determiner is. For example, consider:

> This is merely an example.
>   This is merely one example.

The first is saying that it is an example, and shouldn't be taken as having any other significance. The second is asserting that there are other examples out there that could be chosen. In the second, it is clear that the adverb is modifying the determiner *one*. In the first, it is the "example-ness" that is being modified.

It's not hard to see how linguists end up in knots over this stuff. If you work at it, you can find examples of adverbs applying to pretty much any part of speech, and then you argue about how it should be parsed. The bottom line, really, is that **different adverbs can apply to different things in different situations**, and the important thing is to **learn how they are used rather than coming up with general rules**, because any general rules like that will have to be supplemented by an **immense list of exceptions**.